# What means DEFAULT VALUES specification in an insert query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms, database

I am pretty new in Microsoft **SQL Server** and I am not so into DB in general.

I have the following doubt about an insert query that begin in this way:

```
insert into MyTable DEFAULT VALUES
```

What exactly mean the **DEFAULT VALUES** specification?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Read the manual: Google "tsql insert"

Comment: Please consider referring  Books Online before posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can watch default specifications in work by checking that code:

```
DECLARE @tmp as table 
(
id int null,
num int null default(777),
txt varchar(10) null default('abc'),
date datetime null
)    
insert into @tmp DEFAULT VALUES    
select * from @tmp
```

---

Output is

```
id      num     txt     date
NULL    777     abc     NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

[Reading the fine manual](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) yields:

> DEFAULT VALUES
>
> Forces the new row to contain the default values defined for each column.

Answer (score 2):

Well it uses the default values specified in your table.

So for example if you have a column `CreationDate datetime default(getdate())` it will use it.

Answer (score 2):

If each of the required columns in MyTable has specified DEFAULT VALUE then this statement insert such a row.

For example you could have column Date with default 01/01/2014 and position with DEFAULT 'Developer' and this statement would insert such a record.

You can read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206%28SQL.80%29.aspx